# Conditional Query and Retrieval

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a Google Sheet for our handyman business and need to collect totals on multiple client labor and material activities. I have a pretty decent sheet going, but, since we work for different clients on different days, with lots of other information in between, it would be nice if I could make a cell collect totals from any cell that has their name at the top of the column instead of chasing all over the sheet to get the client's grand total at the end of the week. Kind of like, if any cell in Row 3 has the word (name) Doe in it, return the value in row 10 of the corresponding column (where the labor for that day has been added up for that client on that day). It'd be great if it could add everything up for that client for the week every time their name is mentioned.

Too much to ask? Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can standardize the column that the name will occur in you can use [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to do exactly what you want. You may need to use partial matches as well if you want only check for part of the name https://exceljet.net/formula/partial-match-with-vlookup.